# Show that this congruence has solutions for all primes $p$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Show that the congruence
>   $$(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 3)(x^2 - 6) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } p$$
>   For every prime $p$

I am quite stuck on this problem and not sure how to approach it. Do I argue by contradiction?

Comment: Hint : Consider the quadratic residues

Comment: What do you know about the product of two quadratic non-residues?